# Applying divergence theorem to cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

> Let $D$ be an open subset in the $(x, y)$ plane with smooth boundary and let $X = (X1, X2)$
>   be a continuously differentiable vector field on $\bar{D}$. Make a solid cylinder $C$ by
>   $C = \left \{ (x, y, z) : (x, y) ∈ D, 0 < z < 1 \right \}$.
>   Use $X$ to define a vector field $A$ on $\bar{C}$ by $A = (X1, X2, 0)$. 
>   Apply the Divergence theorem to C and A, with the the answer in terms of an integral over D and an integral over the boundary of D.

I think this question is interesting, but I am completely lost as to where one would start with it?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Brian Thank you, but I genuinely have put in what I know - I don't even know how to begin to approach this one. I know the statement of the divergence theorem and what the elements in the question are individually, but not how to put them together to apply the theorem correctly. I don't want it solved for me, just a starting push in the right direction.

Comment: Let $E$ be the boundary of $D$. then the boundary of $C$ is $D \times \{0\}$ on the bottom and $D \times \{1\}$ on top, while the sides of $C$ are $E \times I$, where $I$ is the interval $(0,1)$. The top and bottom $C$ have normals that are perpendicular to $A$, but the normal to the sides has no contribution in the $z$ direction, since the cylinder is constant in that direction. So the normal points horizontally, just like $A$ does, everywhere.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you calculate the divergence of $(X_1,X_2,0)$?

Comment: @chrystomath is the divergence just divA= dX1/dx + dX2/dy?

Comment: Yes. Now plug into the divergence theorem formula.